# java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: why nio not creating file

Tags: java, file-io, nio

I am using java.nio.file package and tried to create file with the following code.

```
private static void printReport(String filename, String str)throws Exception{

        ErrorCheck ec = new ErrorCheck();
        String fileName = "/var/Emails_log/"+filename;      
        Path filePath = Paths.get(fileName);
        File file = new File(fileName);             
        final BufferedWriter out = Files.newBufferedWriter(filePath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);            

        try{                
            final Path tmp = filePath.getParent();
            if (tmp != null){ // null will be returned if the path has no parent
                    Files.createDirectories(tmp);   
            } else {
                out.write(str);
                out.write('\n');
            }               
        } catch(Exception e) {
            ec.errorMsg("ERROR: GSW.SendEmail.Exception =>",e);
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
        }           
    }
```

This throws following Exception:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/Emails_log/GSWvalidSentAddresses.txt
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:430)
at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:170)
at java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter(Files.java:2720)
at SendEmail.printReport(SendEmail.java:114) SendEmail.send(SendEmail.java:87)
```

My question is why file is not created?

Please advise

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: You should show the code *that causes the exception*. The code you've quoted is *before* the exception (presumably!). It's the call to `newBufferedWriter` that failed. It's really hard to help you with code we can't see.

Comment: check whether /var/Emails_log/ folder exists.

Comment: @PavanKumarK: That's what the first code block is doing.

Comment: Your posted code lacks the creation of `out` but this is where the exception occurs. It doesn’t help trying to create the directories *after* trying to open the file.

Comment: Raakh, Stack Overflow is a *very* active place. When you ask a question, stick around for a few minutes to reply to questions from people trying to help you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Updated Answer**:

Now that you've shown the full code, there are two major problems:

1. You're trying to open the file before ensuring that the directories leading up to it exist, and
2. You're using `StandardOpenOption.APPEND`, but that won't *create* a file; it will append to an *existing* file.

...along with a large number of issues around best practices relative to the number of lines of actual code.

See comments:

```
private static void printReport(String filename, String str) throws Exception /* No, it doesn't. The only calls you had outside your catch-all `try` don't throw exceptions. */ {
    ErrorCheck ec           = new ErrorCheck();            // Recommend not creating this until/unless you need it
    String fileName         = "/var/Emails_log/"+filename; // VERY poor practice having two locals that only differ by the capitalization of one character in the middle (`filename` and `fileName`)
    Path filePath           = Paths.get(fileName);
    //  File file               = new File(fileName);      <== Removed, since you never use it for anything

    try {
        // Make sure the directories exist
        Files.createDirectories(filePath.getParent());  // No need for your null check, so I removed it; based on `fileName`, it will always have a parent

        // Open the file, creating it if it doesn't exist
        try (
            final BufferedWriter out = Files.newBufferedWriter(
                                            filePath,
                                            StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
                                            StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                            StandardOpenOption.APPEND)
        ) {
            // Write to out here
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log-and-continue isn't generally best practice; and if you're going to do it
        ec.errorMsg("ERROR: GSW.SendEmail.Exception =>",e); // <== Um...send mail failed? This isn't sending mail, it's putting something in a file.
    }
    // Using the try-with-resources, we don't have to worry about the flush and close calls
}
```

But here's how I would suggest you write it:

```
private static void printReport(String filename, String str) throws IOException {
    Path filePath           = Paths.get("/var/Emails_log/" + filename);

    // Make sure the directories exist
    Files.createDirectories(filePath.getParent());

    // Open the file, creating it if it doesn't exist
    try (
        final BufferedWriter out = Files.newBufferedWriter(
                                        filePath,
                                        StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
                                        StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                        StandardOpenOption.APPEND)
    ) {
        // Write to out here, perhaps outputting `str`?
    }
}
```

...and handle exceptions in the calling layer. Note that, again, because we're using `try-with-resources`, the `close` is automatic (both when there's an exception and when there isn't).

Or if you really want to do log-and-continue:

```
private static void printReport(String filename, String str) {
    try {
        Path filePath           = Paths.get("/var/Emails_log/" + filename);

        // Make sure the directories exist
        Files.createDirectories(filePath.getParent());

        // Open the file, creating it if it doesn't exist
        try (
            final BufferedWriter out = Files.newBufferedWriter(
                                            filePath,
                                            StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
                                            StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                            StandardOpenOption.APPEND)
        ) {
            // Write to out here, perhaps outputting `str`?
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        new ErrorCheck().errorMsg("ERROR: GSW.SendEmail.Exception =>", e); // <== But surely this message is suspect? I don't see anything sending email here.
    }
}
```

---

**Original Answer**:

You haven't shown the code that's actually failing, which is a call to `newBufferedWriter` ([this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) one, or [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) one). `newBufferedWriter` takes `OpenOption`s, the standard set of which are available from [`StandardOpenOption`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html). Make sure you've specified [`StandardOpenOption.CREATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#CREATE) or [`StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#CREATE_NEW),

If you use one of those flags, and the code in your question is*before* the `newBufferedWriter` call, barring some other problem (permissions) it should work:

```
String fileName         = "/var/Emails_log/"+filename;
Path filePath           = Paths.get(fileName);
final Path tmp          = filePath.getParent();

if (tmp != null) {      // <== Note: There's no point to this check, given
                        // your filename above, the path WILL have a parent.
                        // You could remove the `if` and just use
                        // `Files.createDirectories(tmp)` unless the `fileName`
                        // is actually coming from somewhere else and so could
                        // be a root (roots don't have parents)
    Files.createDirectories(tmp);
}
else {
    out.write(str);     // I assume this is for logging or display?
    out.write('\n');    // Specifically, that it's *not* trying to write
                        // to the file you're trying to create.
}

try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(filePath, StandardOpenOption.CREATE)) {
// ------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // Write to the file here
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that you're misusing the return value from `Path.getParent().` You're assuming that `null` means the path doesn't exist. What it actually means is that the *parent* doesn't exist, e.g. the parent of `C:\``.

Comment: @EJP: No, I'm not saying that `getParent` checks if it *exists*. As I said in the comments above, the check is pointless given the code, because we know there will be a parent of that path. It seems unlikely that's what the OP thinks it does, either, because if that's what the OP thinks it does, the check is kind of backward, isn't it? But I've flagged it up in the answer, pointing out that with `fileName` as shown, it will always have a parent.

Comment: @Raakh: Holger was right, then: You're trying to create the file *before* you make sure the directory it's in exists! Change the order of your code to that in the answer, and it will resolve the problem. You're also using `APPEND`, but `APPEND` won't create a new file.

Comment: @Holger: See above: You were right, he was trying to create the file *before* creating the directories.

Comment: @Raakh: I've updated the answer to address your updated code.

Comment: Thanks all from the bottom of my heart. It's really a superior solution and fix all issues